# Post to one specific class not all classes with the same name

Tags: jquery, ajax, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding class where button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547453/finding-class-where-button-is-clicked)

```
<script>
          var num = 1;
function ajax_post(){ 
$.ajax('javas.php', {
success: function(response) {
      $(".status").html(response);
}, 
data: "num=" + (++num)
});
}

function ajax_posta(){
$.ajax('javas.php', {
success: function(response) {
      $(".status").html(response);
}, 
data: "num=" + (--num)
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.eventer > .button').click(function () {
    ajax_post();
});
alert("lol");
});


</script>
```

This is posting to all classes with the name status, however i want it to only post to the class where the submit button was clicked, there are many duplicate classes as the class is generated in a while loop.
This is the HTML generated in a PHP while loop:

```
echo " <div class = 'eventer'> $timeposted <br>$eventlist <button name='myBtn'     type='button'  onClick='javascript:ajax_post();'>Inc</button>
                          <button name='lol' type='button' value='dec'         onClick='javascript:ajax_posta();'></button></div>
<div class = 'status'>sigh</div>";
```

echo "
";

Comment: Can you please show the HTML-part?

Comment: we need to see your html

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax_post method as

```
function ajax_post(obj){
    $.ajax('javas.php', {   success: function(response) { $(obj).closest('.status').html(response);   },    
    data: "num=" + (++num)   });   }
```

Call this method as
    ajax_post(this);

Comment: @foshoeiyyy    in the button click event                                              $('.eventer > .button').click(function () {     ajax_post(this); });

Comment: Probelm with finding the div with class '.status''. I didn't look into the HTML thay you have updated recently

Comment: @foshoeiyyy   $(obj).parent().next('.status').html(response)

Comment: still nothing, not displaying anything