# Finding class where button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I know i have asked this question many times but i still havnt found the rigth answer.

num needs to be displayed in ONLY the class that the button was clicked in.

```
<script>
var num = 1;
function ajax_post(obj){
$.ajax('javas.php', {   success: function(response) {     $(obj).parent().next('.status').html(response);   },    
data: "num=" + (++num)   });   } 

function ajax_posta(obj){
 $.ajax('javas.php', {   success: function(response) {        
 $(obj).parent().next('.status').html(response);
   },    
    data: "num=" + (--num)   });   } 

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.eventer > .submit').click(function () {
        ajax_post(this);
    });
    alert("lol");
    });


</script>

<br>
<div id = 'eventcontainer' >
```

Eventer Class is created as well as status class (multiple times as it is in a while loop (not specified in the code)

```
    echo " <div class = 'eventer'> $timeposted <br>$eventlist <button name='myBtn'     type='button'  onClick='javascript:ajax_post();'>Inc</button>
    <button name='lol' type='button' value='dec'       onClick='javascript:ajax_posta();'>dec</button></div>
    <div class = 'status'>sigh</div>";
    echo "<br>";


    }



    </div>
```

Nothing happens when i click the buttons in any class, whereas num should display in only the class where the button in the eventer class was clicked.

Please help thanks

Comment: When asking client-side questions posting your PHP is confusing and unhelpful. Post your javascript/html as well as what you are trying to accomplish and what specifically is not working. If you want to be even more helpful you should post a jsfiddle exhibiting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick='javascript:ajax_posta();'`

should be

`onClick='ajax_posta()'`

Are you sure the result is positive? The quality of your asked question is very poor and I can't really understand what you are asking..

What do you mean by "num needs to be displayed in ONLY the class that the button was clicked in."

Comment: well, at the moment, there are many classes of 'eventer' and 'status' all with two buttons on the bottom (of every class), when the button is clicked in one class i want num to only be displayed in that class, not all the other classes with the same name if you know what i mean

Comment: Can you set-up a http://jsfiddle.net/ with several HTML element and leave out the AJAX calls? What you need to do is remove the onClick attribute and handle the click in jQuery $(".eventer button[name=lol]").click(function(){}). Then you can use $(this) to append the value `num`

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/2bwuM/5/
I'm still not sure what it is you're after, but this might help you..
Edit: Updated (5)

Comment: Thanks man, but i when i put this in my code it doesnt work, only works on jsfiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5946/discussion-between-richard-and-foshoeiyyy)

Comment: what would happen if i enable the ajax?